# Sorting an array of hashes with the smallest value in the middle

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I'm new to ruby and didn't manage to find any answer or logic about how can I do this. I'm trying to split an array in half, and half of it to sort it descending, and the other half ascending.

Long story short, lets consider we have the following array of hashes:

```rb
[
 {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
 {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
 {:rating=>3.5, :num=>37},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>23},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>72},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>38}, 
 {:rating=>3.5, :num=>72}, 
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>74}
]
```

I'm not very good at explaining things, but I will try my best to explain better whats the expected result.

First I need to get the hash that has the smallest `:rating` key value and `:num` key value and push it in a new array. The remaining hashes should be sorted asc after `:rating` and `:num` and then, each of the hashes, starting with the one that has the smallest `:rating` value, should be pushed in the new created array following the rule: one in the beginning of the array and one in the end until no hashes remain.

So the final result should look like this:

```rb
[
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>74},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>72},
 {:rating=>3.5, :num=>72},
 {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
 {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
 {:rating=>3.5, :num=>37},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>23},
 {:rating=>4.0, :num=>38}
]
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean as first half?

Comment: You selected an answer that returns an ordering that is considerably different than your desired "final result". What is your justification for doing so?

Comment: I've downvoted your question because it is not clear. Specifically, what is the criterion for partitioning the array before the sorting of the two parts is performed? If you address @iGian's comment (which I don't believe you've seen) by clarifying with an edit, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit complicated solution but it works. Please take a look while I'll try to refactor it

```
initial_array = [
    {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
    {:rating=>1, :num=>1},
    {:rating=>3.5, :num=>37},
    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>23},
    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>72},
    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>38},
    {:rating=>3.5, :num=>72},
    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>74}
]


length = initial_array.length
new_array = []

length.times do |i|
  is_odd = i % 2 == 1
  min_index = initial_array.map{|el| el[:rating]}.each_with_index.min.last
  if is_odd
    new_array.push(initial_array.delete_at(min_index))
  else
    new_array.unshift(initial_array.delete_at(min_index))
  end
end

p new_array
```

The main idea is to find minimum element from the array each time and push it to a new array once from right and once from left.

The minimum value is found by rating (`map{|el| el[:rating]}`) however you can implement some more complex function that will utilize both `rating` and `num` depending on your business logic.

Comment: This returns `[{:rating=>4.0, :num=>38}, {:rating=>4.0, :num=>23}, {:rating=>3.5, :num=>37}, {:rating=>1, :num=>1}, {:rating=>1, :num=>1}, {:rating=>3.5, :num=>72}, {:rating=>4.0, :num=>72}, {:rating=>4.0, :num=>74}]`, which bears little resemblance to the OP's  desired "final result".

Comment: Actually, my answer follows the general idea - minimal in the middle and increase step by step toward the endings. If you want to get exactly the same answer as in the question just change `is_odd` determination to `is_odd = i % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The only interpretation I can think of for "split an array in half" that is consistent with your desired result, is that the hashes that are to be sorted in ascending order are those hashes `h` for which `h[:num]` is less than the average of the values `h[:num]` for all hashes `h` in the array, and that the remaining hashes are to be sorted in ascending order.

Assuming this interpretation is correct, and letting the variable `arr` hold your array, the desired sorted array can be obtained as follows.

```
avg = arr.sum { |h| h[:num] }.fdiv(arr.size)
  #=> 39.75

arr.sort_by { |h| h[:num] < avg ? [h[:rating], h[:num]] : [-h[:rating], -h[:num]] }
  #=> [{:rating=>4.0, :num=>74},
  #    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>72},
  #    {:rating=>3.5, :num=>72},
  #    {:rating=>1,   :num=> 1},
  #    {:rating=>1,   :num=> 1},
  #    {:rating=>3.5, :num=>37},
  #    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>23},
  #    {:rating=>4.0, :num=>38}]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. This also works great. Thank you!

Comment: Is the interpretation I set out in my first paragraph correct? Regardless, you need to edit your question to clarify "split an array in half".